# How to root Sony Xperia C3 Dual D2502 running Android 5.0.2?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rooting, sony-xperia-c3-dual

I use Sony Xperia C3 Dual D2502. I've installed Android  5.0.2 and now I can't root it.  I can't root it using Sony Flashtool method.

- Model Number: D2502
- Kernel Version: 3.4.0+
- Build Number: 19.3.A.0.470

**How can I root it?**

Comment: What are the error messages if you try to root it your way?

Comment: No error messages but the phone doesn't start after using the method,  then I've to install the firmware again :(

Answer (score 1):

To root you must follow this handy tips

1) Before getting started with the rooting procedure, take a complete backup of personal data in your smartphone using appropriate apps. If you don’t take backup and follow the procedure given below, then your personal data will be wiped out, and you can’t recover them at all.

2) Ensure that your device has a good battery backup or else charge it fully, before carrying out the procedure.

3) Download Sony Xperia USB drivers and install it in your computer, so that you can connect Xperia C3 with it.

4) Enable USB Debugging mode in your device by following the path: Settings -> Developer Options -> USB Debugging Mode (tick the box to enable it).

When done you can start rooting

1) To get started, you have to unlock the bootloader of your Xperia C3. To do that, visit this page and follow the instructions given there to get the Unlock CODE (which will be sent to your email address).

2) Next, download Flashtool and install in your computer. Once done, switch off your device and connect it to the computer while holding the volume down button until the phone LED turns into blue color.

3) Now, click BLU on the flash tool and follow the onscreen instructions. Once it is done, disconnect your Xperia C3 from the computer and reconnect it to the computer while holding the Volume up button until you see the Flashtool asking for the Unlock code (Step 1). Just enter it and your device bootloader will be unlocked.

4) Next, download CWM and SuperSU, extract and save them to your computer. Once done, connect your Xperia C3 to the computer while holding the Volume DOWN button until you Blue color in the LED.

5) Now, open flash tool and select Fastboot mode. Next choose “Kernel To Flash” followed by “*.img” and finally choose the boot.img that you have got after extracting the CWM recovery (Step 4). The flashing process will begin and within few seconds will get completed. Once done, disconnect your Xperia C3 from the computer.

6) Next, switch on your device, connect it to the computer using USB debugging mode and transfer the SuperSU.zip file (Step 4) to the SD card. Once done, disconnect your device again.

7) Now, switch off your smartphone again. We have to boot into the recovery mode for flashing SuperSU. To do that, switch on your device while holding the Volume UP button until you boot into the recovery mode.

8) In CWM recovery, select “Install Zip from SD card”, choose the SuperSU file that you have transferred to the SD (Step 6) and start the flashing process. Once it is done, Reboot your device normally.

You can find the contents here: http://www.androidrootguide.com/list-android-custom-roms-official-roms-root-software-download-links from CWM to the rom

That is one way the other way to root your phone is to get UnlockRootPro. You connect your device and then select it from the dropdown menu and click root. But remember to do the handy tips on the first link.

Comment: Link only answer does not help if the link becomes dead later, and for the _other way to root_ could you share the link for the app, steps to perform?